# Drupal: another way to fetch the taxonomy tid (apart from URL)

Tags: drupal-7

I am using webforms which have as the topic taxonomy terms saved as hidden fields.

Unfortunate, after attaching files using Upload button this terms are lost ('No category'), as ajax is altering the form #action URL from /tid to /file/ajax/submitted/file4/form-gTwVpNbQRszArGEUS1OfuwA8WgSLJOlcWGOuS6r9D5A

From where to read $tid?

Therefore my $tid fail to load from URL

```
function MYMODULE_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
$tid = arg(1);
          $term = taxonomy_term_load($tid);
            if (!empty($term)) {
                $category = i18n_taxonomy_term_name($term, $language->language);
            } else {
                $category = 'No category';
            }
            $form['submitted'][$category_fieldkey] = array(
                '#type' => 'hidden',
                '#value' => $category,
            );

}
```